# Named ObjectMarshallers in Grails 2 with parent child relationships

Tags: grails, marshalling

I need to use Multiple Named Object Marshallers for a grails project.  I had no problem writing or registering these marshallers and they work for simple classes.  The problem is using them with parent-child relationships (like Employer/Employees).  I am calling a marshaller with

```
JSON.use('marshallerName')
```

but this only works for the object that the marshaller is registered to (whether it be the parent or the child).

Is there any way I can call multiple Object Marshallers on a parent/child relationship.

The `JsonApi` plugin will not work for me in this situation for other reasons.